# Failed to access variables among the tasks in AzureDevops

Tags: azure-devops

I have creates below task to find the current tag and pass on to next tasks while building the docker image with new tag.

```
- task: Bash@3
        displayName: 'Fetch latest tag from ECR and Create Next Tag.'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            ecrURI=$(ecrURI)
            repoName="${ecrURI##*/}"
            latestECRTag=$(aws ecr describe-images  --output json  --repository-name ${repoName} --region $(awsDefaultRegion) --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]' | jq . --raw-output)
            if [[ -z ${latestECRTag} ]];
            then
                latestECRTag='0.0.0'
            fi
            major=$(echo ${latestECRTag} |cut -d'.' -f1)
            minor=$(echo ${latestECRTag} |cut -d'.' -f2)
            patch=$(echo ${latestECRTag} |cut -d'.' -f3)
            latestECRTag="$(expr $major + 1).${minor}.${patch}"
            echo $latestECRTag
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NEXT_ECR_TAG;isOutput=true]$latestECRtag"
- bash: |
          echo "Started Building Docker Image with tag $latestECRTag"
          docker build -t test:latest -f Dockerfile .
          docker tag test:latest $(ecrURI):$(NEXT_ECR_TAG)

        displayName: 'Build Docker Image with Tag.'
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/configCreate/
```

The step/task to fetch and create the new tag is working fine, but as soon as I moved to the next task to build the docker tag based on `NEXT_ECR_TAG` it shows me empty value. everything else are properly populated.

Can anyone help me to find out why i'm not able to fetch the `NEXT_ECR_TAG` value in next task? It could be silly thing, but don't know what?

Answer (score 0):

duh!! moment for me. there is a typo in my variable. Fixing typo fixed everything.